# Is there a way to use parameter substitution to run one curl against two different servers?

Tags: bash

This is the best page I could find to help with this, I don't see what I want to do on there: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe. But I think I've seen this done before.

Say I want to run the same query against Bing and Google (let's assume these would work):

`curl -S "https://www.google.com?q=stackoverflow"`

`curl -S "https://www.bing.com?q=stackoverflow"`

Could I run them both in one `curl`? Like `curl -S "https://www.${'bing','google'}.com?q=stackoverflow"`

I'd swear I've seen this done before. But I clearly have the syntax wrong. As well as the search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl understand (and expand) braces:

```
curl -S 'https://www.{bing,google}.com?q=stackoverflow;'
```

From man curl:

> URL
>   You can specify multiple URLs … by writing part sets within braces as in:
>
> ```
>     http://site.{one,two,three}.com
> ```

This is different to shell brace expansions, Curl will *not* expand Nested braces like the following shell code example will:

```
$ echo {{1..3},{5..7}}
1 2 3 5 6 7
```

Comment: Was it the `$` that as goofing me up?

Comment: `curl -S "https://www.{bing,google}.com?q=stackoverflow;"` is simpler and works, is it wrong?

Comment: You said it must be unquoted but you quoted it. Confusing.

Comment: `curl -S "https://www.{bing,google}.com?q=stackoverflow;"` does expand... I get 2 curls when I run that.

Comment: @jcollum Answer re-written. Yes, the `$` seem to be the biggest problem you had.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Yes, just Read again, hope my intent is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

handled by shell as two url parameters:

```
curl -S https://www.{bing,google}.com\?q=stackoverflow
```

handled by internal curl syntax in single url param:

```
curl -S https://www.\{bing,google\}.com\?q=stackoverflow
```